# How to blur objects in fabric js (NOT AN IMAGE)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

Can we blur objects in Canvas with fabricjs like rectangle,polygon.At least soft that objects edges.

**update:**

I have an another approach for this, we can blur objects shadow. So Blur object shadow than set offset to opposite direction like this :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("my-canvas");

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    top: -600,
    left: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    opacity: 0.5
});
rect.setShadow({
     color: 'red',
     blur: 7,
     offsetX: 0,
     offsetY: 700
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="my-canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

but problem is we can't use `globalCompositeOperation` option for this

Answer (score 0):

see fabric demo: http://fabricjs.com/image-filters

on checkbox blur code:

```
$('blur').onclick = function() {
applyFilter(9, this.checked && new f.Convolute({
  matrix: [ 1/9, 1/9, 1/9,
            1/9, 1/9, 1/9,
            1/9, 1/9, 1/9 ]
}));}
```

it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve via CSS

```
filter: blur(X%)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=contrast(200%25)

Comment: It will blur the whole canvas, I guess

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can make the object transparent and apply a blurred shadow:

```
var shadow = new fabric.Shadow({
      color: 'white',
      blur: 7,
      offsetX: 20,
      offsetY: 20,
    })

var myObject = new fabric.Polygon(
      {
        ... other props
        shadow: shadow,
      }
    )
```

Answer (score -4):

`fabricjs` is a high-level library for the HTML5 `canvas` API. In fabric, you work on the canvas object itself, not the context. To blur an object, simply set the `opacity` property for that object.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("my-canvas");

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    opacity: 0.5
});

canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="my-canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually I want to make object hard edge to soft edge . opacity is not a good idea for that.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to answer the question. Anyways, what does hard edge to soft edge mean? That may help me get some ideas

Comment: hard edge simply means normal fabricjs rectangle. soft edge means like this [link](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/fillslinesandeffects/images/softedgeoptions2010_2.jpg)